# SDL Web Topology Manager in IIS

Tags: web8, topology-manager

In [Rob Stevenson-Leggett's post](http://www.blog.electricbiro.co.uk/2015/12/04/sdl-web-8-wtf-is-topology-manager/) he noted a website in IIS called SDL Web Topology Manager.

[image: SDL Web Topology Managere]

Questions:

1. Is this in the Content Manager?
2. What does it do? Or in other words, should implementers be able to do anything with it?

For example, browsing to the site returned Rob a 500 error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is (surprisingly) Topology Manager website which hosts odata service inside.

The proper endpoint is `http://host:port/ttm201501`.

There you can browse/add/remove Topology Manager entities using GET/POST requests (if you do not want to use powershell for some reason, which does it behind the scenes).

Comment: Ah, it's obvious now. :-) As we release new versions, might that endpoint change? It looks like a year and date in `201501`.

Comment: It is the same endpoint version as for CoreService.