# Topology Manager | Unable to Add Cd topology type

Tags: topology-manager, web8

I am not able to add Topology  type using the command Add-TtmCdTopologyType. It throws 500 error.

> PS C:\Users\Administrator> Add-TtmCdTopologyType -Id StaginAndLive -Name "Staging and Live" -EnvironmentPurposes "Staging,live"
>   Add-TtmCdTopologyType : Error occurred while attempting to communicate with Topology Manager Service at
>   'http://localhost:83/ttm201501'. The server returned the following response code: 500 (InternalServerError).
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Add-TtmCdTopologyType -Id StaginAndLive -Name "Staging and Live" -EnvironmentPur ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Tridion.Topolog...logyTypeCommand:AddCdTopologyTypeCommand) [Add-TtmCdTop
>      ologyType], DataServiceException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.AddCdTopologyTypeCommand

Please help

Thanks

Comment: are you able to browse 'http://localhost:83/ttm201501' - your topology manager webapp?

Comment: Check the logs.

Comment: Hi Mukesh , Thanks for your reply. I am not able to browse this URL. It says "localhost refused to connect"

Comment: I also note the inconsistent naming StaginAndLive (instead of StagingAndLive), "Staging,live" no capital L for live - could these be of any impact?

Comment: Ok , if you are not able to browse then that's the issue, please see http://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/14259/1449 , you need to get this working for adding TopologyType etc